# how to check if a record exists in Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, select, exists

i can't seem to get the code working to determine how to check if a record exists in Mysql table.
Im not very good at this but i'm learning.
i would like to check if a certain barcode exists in my table called users.

i get the following error when i execute the code below.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\see.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\watermeters\see.php on line 14
```

See the code below.
Can someone help me with this code?

```
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "watermeter");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$query = "SELECT barcode from users where barcode='5645454'";
$result = mysql_query($link, $query);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    // row exists. do whatever you would like to do.
} else {

    // row does not exists. do whatever you would like to do.
}




// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is a typo, `mysqli_query `

Comment: you want `mysqli_query` not `mysql_query`

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` also needs to chabge

Comment: PHP has three different MySQL interfaces: mysql, mysqli, and PDO. The mysql interface uses function names that start with `mysql_`. These have been deprecated and are not available in new PHP versions -- don't use these. The mysqli interface uses function names that start with `mysqli_`. The PDO interface is object oriented only. See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) for more details and some good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli

Use `mysqli_query`

Comment: So simple, thank you Andrei Lupuleasa, Thank you all!!